# Returning the frequency of words

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following text:

```
Grier et al. (1983) reported father and 2 sons with typical Aarskog
syndrome, including short stature, hypertelorism, and shawl scrotum.
They tabulated the findings in 82 previous cases. X-linked recessive
inheritance has repeatedly been suggested (see 305400). The family
reported by Welch (1974) had affected males in 3 consecutive
generations. Thus, there is either genetic heterogeneity or this is an
autosomal dominant with strong sex-influence and possibly ascertainment
bias resulting from use of the shawl scrotum as a main criterion.
Stretchable skin was present in the cases of Grier et al. (1983).
```

I'm trying to return the list of words in the text above.

I did something as follows:

```
input_file.read.downcase.scan(/\b[a-z]\b/) {|word| frequency[word] = frequency[word] + 1}
```

I get the letters (i.e. `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `z`) and their frequency in the document, and not the words. Why is that? And, how can I get the words instead of only standalone letters?

Comment: the regex you want is: `/\b[a-z]+\b/` you want one or more characters

Comment: `input_file.read.downcase.scan(/\b[a-z]+\b/)`

Comment: `[a-z]` matches single char only.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. If we write "\b[a-z]{3,16}\b", will that return us only words with sizes ranging from 3 and 16, and we don't need the "+" after [a-z]?

Comment: Is "X" to be one of the words?

Comment: If `str = "Être ou ne pas être" then str.downcase.scan(/\b[a-z]+\b/) #=> ["ou", "ne", "pas"]` vs. (POSIX) `str.downcase.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/) #=> ["Être", "ou", "ne", "pas", "être"]` (or `/\p{Alpha}+/`). Note "Être" is not downcased in the latter, because downcasing is language-specific. See the gem [unicode-util](http://unicode-utils.rubyforge.org/) for that.

Answer (score 3):

http://rubular.com is a great resource.

`\b[a-z]\b` says any single character between two word boundaries.

If you would like to allow for multiple characters use this: `\b[a-z]+\b`

That says any one or more letters between two word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If we write "\b[a-z]{3,16}\b", will that return us only words with sizes ranging from 3 and 16, and we don't need the "+" after [a-z]?

Comment: @simplicity that's correct - {x,y} means at least x, at most y.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
text = 'Foo. (1983). Bar baz foo bar.'
text.downcase
# => "foo. (1983). bar baz foo bar."
```

`downcase` folds the text to lower-case to make it easy to find matches for the words regardless of case.

```
text.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '')
# => "foo  bar baz foo bar"
```

`gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '')` removes characters that aren't part of words, like punctuation and numbers.

```
text.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '').split
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar"]
```

`split` will break a string into "words" that are space-delimited.

```
text.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '').split.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0}){ |w, h| h[w] += 1 }
# => {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>2, "baz"=>1}
```

`each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0}){ |w, h| h[w] += 1 }` is how to walk through an array and count the frequency of elements. `Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0}` is how to define a hash that will automatically create `0` values for keys that don't exist.

With all that in mind:

```
text = 'Grier et al. (1983) reported father and 2 sons with typical Aarskog syndrome, including short stature, hypertelorism, and shawl scrotum. They tabulated the findings in 82 previous cases. X-linked recessive inheritance has repeatedly been suggested (see 305400). The family reported by Welch (1974) had affected males in 3 consecutive generations. Thus, there is either genetic heterogeneity or this is an autosomal dominant with strong sex-influence and possibly ascertainment bias resulting from use of the shawl scrotum as a main criterion. Stretchable skin was present in the cases of Grier et al. (1983).'
text.downcase
    .gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '')
    .split
    .each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0}){ |w, h| h[w] += 1 }
```

Which results in:

```
# => {"grier"=>2, "et"=>2, "al"=>2, "reported"=>2, "father"=>1, "and"=>3, "sons"=>1, "with"=>2, "typical"=>1, "aarskog"=>1, "syndrome"=>1, "including"=>1, "short"=>1, "stature"=>1, "hypertelorism"=>1, "shawl"=>2, "scrotum"=>2, "they"=>1, "tabulated"=>1, "the"=>4, "findings"=>1, "in"=>3, "previous"=>1, "cases"=>2, "xlinked"=>1, "recessive"=>1, "inheritance"=>1, "has"=>1, "repeatedly"=>1, "been"=>1, "suggested"=>1, "see"=>1, "family"=>1, "by"=>1, "welch"=>1, "had"=>1, "affected"=>1, "males"=>1,...
```

If you insist on using a regex and `scan`:

```
text.downcase
    .scan(/\b [a-z]+ \b/x)
    .each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0}){ |w, h| h[w] += 1 } 
# => {"grier"=>2, "et"=>2, "al"=>2, "reported"=>2, "father"=>1, "and"=>3, "sons"=>1, "with"=>2, "typical"=>1, "aarskog"=>1, "syndrome"=>1, "including"=>1, "short"=>1, "stature"=>1, "hypertelorism"=>1, "shawl"=>2, "scrotum"=>2, "they"=>1, "tabulated"=>1, "the"=>4, "findings"=>1, "in"=>3, "previous"=>1, "cases"=>2, "x"=>1, "linked"=>1, "recessive"=>1, "inheritance"=>1, "has"=>1, "repeatedly"=>1, "been"=>1, "suggested"=>1, "see"=>1, "family"=>1, "by"=>1, "welch"=>1, "had"=>1, "affected"=>1, ...
```

The difference really is that `gsub().split` is faster than `scan(/\b [a-z]+ \b/x)`.